# Updating a tkinter window

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Here's my code (python 2.7):

```
    while x < 10:
        #other code here
        root = Tkinter.Tk()
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(bg) #bg is a valid image that was previously generated
        panel = Tkinter.Label(root, image = img)
        panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
        root.update_idletasks()
        root.update()
```

This code is running inside a while loop. The image bg is essentially a countdown clock, so a new image is being generated every second and I need that image to be shown on the window. I don't have much experience using tkinter, but I understand I need to use the update() and update_idletasks() to update the window, because using mainloop() pauses execution of the program. Well, when I use mainloop() the proper image shows, and if I manually close the window, the next window (the previous clock minus 1 second) will appear. However, with the code I have now, I receive the following: TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist

Comment: To make a thing happen periodically, use `root.after` rather than a loop.

Comment: if you use `update`, you don't need `update_idletasks`; the former is a superset of the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out instead of `root=Tkinter.Tk()` it needs to be `root=Tkinter.Toplevel()`

Comment: @user3246167 If I set `root=Tkinter.Toplevel()` I get the errormessage that Tkinter is not recognized. If I set `root=Toplevel()` then two windows pop up, one with my normal visualisation (but still with the wrongs listed above) and another smaller one with nothing inside and the name tk

Comment: @BryanOakley what exactly do you mean? Where do I have another instance of Tk except `root`